# issue to replace null values in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, null

I am experiencing issue to replace null values by `0` in some `PySpark` dataframe.

Let `df1` and `df2` two dataframes. After a `join` procedure on `col1`, I get a dataframe `df`, which contains two columns with same column name (maybe with different values) inherited from `df1` and `df2`, let say `df1.dup_col` and `df2.dup_col`. I have null values on each of them, I want to replace them by `0` in `df1.dup_col`.

So, first I drop the `df2.dup_col` columns, then I call

```
df.fillna({"df1.dup_col":'0'})
```

but I still get the `null` values. So I tried,

```
df.select("df1.dup_col").na.fill(0)
```

with the same result. So I tried

```
df = df.withColumn("df1.dup_col", when(df["df1.dup_col"].isNull(), 0).otherwise(
                                         df["df1.dup_col"]))
```

with no better result.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like :

```
df = df.fillna("0", subset = ["dup_col"]) # This is the string 0 

df = df.fillna(0, subset = ["dup_col"]) # This is the number 0
```

Answer (score 0):

df = df.fillna({'colName':'value_to_replace'})